# Создать многомерный массив из текстового файла

Tags: php, массивы

средствами PHP я открываю файл .txt и создаю массив из каждой строки с помощью:

```
$file_txt = file('log.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
print_r ($file_txt);
```

Результат выполнения выглядит так:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 15.02.2019 14:38:41 -- folders/ -- 91.210.222.132 -- test.txt -- UPLOAD
    [1] => 15.02.2019 14:40:21 -- folders/ -- 91.210.222.132 -- test.txt -- DELETE
    [2] => 15.02.2019 14:49:38 -- folders/ -- 91.210.222.132 -- test.txt -- UPLOAD
    [3] => 15.02.2019 14:49:59 -- folders/ -- 91.210.222.132 -- test.txt -- DELETE
    [4] => 15.02.2019 22:57:36 -- folders/ -- 40.236.160.24 -- test.txt -- UPLOAD
    [5] => 15.02.2019 22:58:33 -- folders/ -- 40.236.160.24 -- test.txt -- DELETE
)
```

Но у меня не получается разбить каждую строку ещё на массивы и объединить всё в один многомерный массив, для разделения строки я хотел бы использовать

```
$arr = explode(" -- ", $file_txt);
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно создать многомерный массив, чтобы я потом мог выполнить поиск по этому массиву с помощью следующих условий:

```
if(((array_search($ip,$arr)!==false) && (array_search($file,$arr)!==false) && array_search($action,$arr)!==false))
    { echo 'найдено'; }
else { echo 'не найдено'; } // показать, только если не найдено!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил к Вашему массиву ключи и немного изменил поиск.

```
$arr = array();
$keys = array("date", "path", "ip", "file", "action");
$file = file('log.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

foreach ($file as $value)
{
  $a = explode(" -- ", $value);
  $b = array();
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++) 
  {
    $b[$keys[$i]] = $a[$i];
  }
  $arr[] = $b;
}

$ip = "40.236.160.24";
$file = "test.txt";
$action = "UPLOAD";

if(in_array($ip, array_column($arr, 'ip')) && in_array($file, array_column($arr, 'file')) && in_array($action, array_column($arr, 'action'))) 
{
    echo 'найдено'; 
}
else
{
  echo 'не найдено';
}
```

Результат:

```
найдено
```

Поиск ключа по ip и вывод найденных строк:

```
$keys = array_keys(array_column($arr, 'ip'), $ip);
foreach($keys as $k)
{
  var_dump($arr[$k]);
}
```

Comment: Отлично, а я не мог понять как же сделать многомерный массив из всего, спасибо!

Comment: Такой вопрос - а вывести найденные значения правильно можно? Потому что если я пытаюсь вывести как print_r ($arr); - он выводит весь массив, если print_r ($arr[$i]); - выводит последнее значение, action не соответствует заявленному

Comment: Вы хотите по ключу вывести массив, который был найдет? Правильно понимаю?

Comment: Можно массив, можно и через echo результат

Comment: Так как у Вас нет уникального поля, кроме времени. Я могу только предложить сделать поиск по ip всех ключей, а затем вывести их, к сожалению по другому не знаю. Добавил к ответу.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, пригодится :-)